# How can I uninstall dotnet core from macOS Sierra

Tags: .net-core, macos-sierra

I have tried to install dotnet core, but it does not worked. So, I would like to uninstall it and start refresh. How can I uninstall dotnet core from macOS Sierra(10.12.3).

you can find below, existing dotnet core info on the system

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    4 root  wheel   136 May 20 18:28 .
drwxr-xr-x   10 root  wheel   340 May 20 20:44 ..
drwxr-xr-x  142 root  wheel  4828 May 20 20:44 1.0.4
drwxr-xr-x  121 root  wheel  4114 May  9 23:04 2.0.0-preview1-005977


/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk$ sudo find / -name dotnet
find: /dev/fd/sdk: No such file or directory
find: /dev/fd/sdk: No such file or directory
/private/etc/paths.d/dotnet
/Users/melihtt/.dotnet/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers/1.1.0/analyzers/dotnet
/Users/melihtt/.dotnet/optimizationdata/2.0.0-preview1-005977/osx.10.12-x64/dotnet
/usr/local/share/dotnet
/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.5/dotnet
/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.2/dotnet
```

Comment: You can just delete the directories `/usr/local/share/dotnet` and `/Users/melihtt/.dotnet`.  Also, you may want to delete `/Users/melihtt/.nuget` as well to clean any left-over cached nuget packages.

Comment: Just remove all dotnet folders.

Comment: .NET Core Uninstall Tool https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-uninstall-docs

Answer (score 138):

To uninstall dotnet core from macOS:

1. download `dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh` from https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/main/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh
2. make `dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh` executable
3. execute `dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh` as root (requires superuser privileges to run).

```sh
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/sdk/main/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh
chmod u+x dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh
sudo ./dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The official uninstaller binary would not help me with this, but link you provided cleaned up my system.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the M1 Mac

1. Confirm your cpu architecture

   ls /usr/local/share/dotnet/
2. This may be x64 or x86. Set a variable to store the cpu arch

   arch="x64"
3. Confirm your dotnet version

   dotnet --version
4. Set a variable to store the version

   version="5.0.403"
5. Run the following commands

   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/$arch/sdk/$version

   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/$arch/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/$version

   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/$arch/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/$version

   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/$arch/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/$version

   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/$arch/host/fxr/$version
6. Some of the above folders may not exist but that is fine. Confirm that no dotnet sdk is still present

   ls /usr/local/share/dotnet/$arch/sdk/
   dotnet --version

Comment: If you do this, there will still be packages for these files shown in `pkgutil --pkgs`

Answer (score 6):

To uninstall dotnet core from **MacOS**, using **dotnet-uninstall-tool**.

1. Download the tool [**Here**](https://github.com/dotnet/cli-lab/releases)
2. Open terminal and change working directory to where the file (dotnet-core-uninstall.tar.gz) is located.
3. Install the Tool using following commands.

   ```
      1. mkdir -p ~/dotnet-core-uninstall
      2. tar -zxf dotnet-core-uninstall.tar.gz -C ~/dotnet-core-uninstall
      3. cd ~/dotnet-core-uninstall
   ```

**show help:**  ./dotnet-core-uninstall -h

4. ./dotnet-core-uninstall list

Using this command you can check the list of .NET Core SDKS or Runtime that can be removed with this tool.

5. ./dotnet-core-uninstall remove --sdk/--runtime version --force

**Eg:** For remove SDK 5.0.100

./dotnet-core-uninstall remove --sdk 5.0.100 --force

**If you face any Privilege issue add **sudo** in front of the command**

6. Give the user Key (Password).
7. (Do you want to continue) hit the "Y" then enter.

**Check & conform the SDK list**

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use dotnet-core-uninstall tool which allow you to select a specific SDK or runtime version to remove. [github](https://github.com/dotnet/cli-lab/releases) [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=macos)

If you are experiencing issues with building Xamarin.Mac after installing preview version of .Net 5 SDK you might like to remove Mono [using such script](https://github.com/gurza/cli-toolbox/blob/master/dotnet/mono-uninstall.sh) and Visual Studio [like this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/master/mac/resources/uninstall-vsmac.sh) and try to reinstall from scratch

good luck