# identityserver4 the remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: untrustedroot

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, ssl-certificate, identityserver4

I am hosting my IdentityServer, Web API and MVC client apps all with IIS server, under HTTPS. When I run the my MVC client I get the following error back (note - 6009 is the port of my MVC client and 6005 is the port of my IdentityServer):

[image]

I am using IIS Express Development Certificate for all projects when I configure them in IIS:

[image]

and I copied the certificate from the personal store to the trusted root as the following:

[image]

and here is the details of the cert:

[image]

what else am I missing here?

Comment: You can refer to the [official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#os-x---certificate-not-trusted),and try the commands in it.If it still cannot work,you can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64984519/dotnet-5-on-mac-with-is4-returns-ssl-connection-could-not-be-established)

Comment: Thanks Yiyi You. The "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" command worked for me.

Comment: Hello,I have changed my comment to an answer,if it is helpful,can you accept it as answer?Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I would love to do that. Thanks again, Yiyi You!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can refer to the [official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#os-x---certificate-not-trusted),and try the commands in it.

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Answer (score 12):

For me, neither `dotnet dev-certs https --clean/trust` nor manually cleaning the Windows certificate stores worked out.

Since I was using Docker and Kestrel (instead of ISS), for some reason, it was using outdated certificates located under: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https\<project-name>.pfx` The `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` command did not clean up the certificates in this directory.

After cleaning the certificates in this directory, everything worked again. I'm aware that your problem is already resolved, but since this is a common issue I figured I would also post my solution here.

Related issue about why the clean command does not clean these certs can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15357

Comment: Thank you very much! Took some time to find that answer that solved the issue.

Comment: Running the clean command, deleting the files from ```ASP.NET\Https``` and then running trust again, fixed my problem.
Faced it for a couple of days, many thanks !

Comment: Did the trick for me aswell!