# Why is no certificate found when I run `dotnet dev-certs -c`, but when I run `dotnet dev-certs --trust` it says there is already a valid certifcate

Tags: .net, macos, keychain, dotnet-dev-certs

I'm on a Mac and I cannot get dotnet to recognize my dev-cert, preventing me from running https on localhost.

When I run `dotnet dev-certs https -c -v`, I get back `No valid certificate found.`

But when I run `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`, I get back `A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.` Or after I've deleted my certs in the keychaining I get `The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully.`

What would give these two commands different responses, why can one find it, and the other can't?

I've tried deleting the localhost certs in my keychain and regenerating them. I've tried that with 3 different major versions of the dotnet SDK. They generate just fine, but I always get the same result when running the aforementioned commands. I've tried running the `dotnet certs https --clean` command, but that doesn't actually work. I have to go into the keychain and delete them manually. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the `dotnet-dev-certs` tool with `dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-dev-certs`, but haven't had any luck. And I've tried running all the commands mentioned with `sudo`, just in case.

Why would the `https --trust` command say there's already a valid cert, but nothing else can find it? Even though it's in the keychain?

Alternatively, is there another way to run https with kestrel? Like a way to generate a self-signed cert in the root of a project and then point to that?

Comment: Upvoting the question. This is exactly what I am facing right now. Were you able to resolve this problem by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Could be a few reasons for this issue. I found three while trying to fix mine.

### 1. Something wrong with dotnet.

When you run the command:

```
dotnet dev-certs https
```

The usual response must be something like that:

```
% dotnet dev-certs https
The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully.
```

And when you run the command

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

You must get a response which looks like:

```
% dotnet dev-certs https --trust
Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. If the certificate is not already trusted we will run the following command:
'sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <<certificate>>'
This command might prompt you for your password to install the certificate on the system keychain.
A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.
```

Here, the last line could either say `A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.` or it could say that the certificate was trusted successfully, depending on whether you executed the command once or more than that.

However, if running these commands give a result that look like this:
[image]
It means that there is definitely something wrong with your version of dotnet. I suggest to uninstall dotnet from your mac, and try to reinstall it from the official website.

Here is a quick and effective way to uninstall dotnet:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44089766/1928149

Now try adding the certificates again.

### 2. Dotnet may not be able to access the keychain.

In this case, run the following two commands:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --check
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
```

Now, just go to your `Keychain Access` app in macbook, search for certificates with the name `localhost` and delete them. (You can also drag and drop it to one of your folders before deleting, in case you need a backup.)

Once you have removed all certificates, run the following:

```
dotnet dev-certs https
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Now, when you run the following:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --check --trust
```

You should find a certificate which is available as well as trusted.

### 3. CryptographicException while reading the certificates.

Run the following command:

```
dotnet dev-certs https -v
```

This should display some debug information about your certificates. If the output gives an exception which is something like:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException certificate 'certificate-name` is corrupted
```

or

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: ASN1 corrupted data
```

This is how it looked for me:
[image: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException]

This means dotnet is having issues in reading certificates from your keychain because of a particular unrelated certificate. Go to your `Keychain Access` app and look for the certificate `certificate-name` as shown in the logs above. Keep a backup of this certificate and delete it from your `Keychain Access` app. Try to run the following command again:

```
dotnet dev-certs https -v
```

Hopefully, it lists certificates without any exceptions now.

Now, follow `Point #2` above and hopefully things should now work.

Comment: I had an invalid certificate which was causing my issue. After getting its name, I just deleted it from Keychain Access and everything went back to working normally. Thanks a lot