# Dotnet CLI not working after uninstalling the SDKs and Runtimes from x64 folder on M1 machine

Tags: macos-sierra, dotnet-cli

Problem is that I can't use dotnet CLI anymore..
It throws the following error `A fatal error occurred, the folder [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/host/fxr] does not contain any version-numbered child folders`

Can you help me fix it?

I've been having problems with C# Dev Kit for VS Code and noticed that my SDK and Runtimes for .NET  live under /usr/local/share/dotnet/**x64**/sdk when I actually use MacBook M1 with ARM architecture.

I decided to remove the sdks and runtimes from there and reinstall them with appropriate microsoft .pkg for arm64 architecture.

I did so, I ran bunch of `rm -rf` commands in that **x64** folder, reinstalled the SDK 7.0.12 and now it's pointing to a proper /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk folder.

In relation to other posts I can confirm I never used homebrew to install my previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the easiest I could do is to get `dotnet uninstaller` tool. Just got rid of the whole dot net all together and installed it again with a proper .pkg file from microsoft website.

This post helped me: [How can I uninstall dotnet core from macOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089518/how-can-i-uninstall-dotnet-core-from-macos-sierra)